# An object that can be passed to ExecutorService, and has a dependency between Runnables

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice, completable-future

I'm trying to create a object that has a dependency in it. The point is, a class that has an ExecutorService and a class that generates Runnables are different. Here's the simple abstraction:

```
public class Main {
  private ExecutorService pool; // Initialized before executing main
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Batch> batches = // fetching...
    for(Batch batch : batches) {
      Runnable r = batch.getRunnable();
      pool.submit(r);
    }
  }
}

public class Batch {
  public Runnable getRunnable() {
    Runnable r1 = // creating...
    Runnable r2 = // creating...
    // FIXME: demand that r2 run after r1 finishes
    return // something suitable. r1? r2? or new Runnable?
  }
}
```

I used to use CompletableFuture when these classes are one:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(r1, pool)
                 .thenRunAsync(r2, pool)
                 .exceptionally(ex -> { // Do something });
```

But now `pool` resides in another class. I'm seeing the CompletableFuture class's document more, but I'm still not sure it can help.

Does anyone have some knowledge around here?

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient if your `Batch` returned a List of `Runnable`? Then you could use `runAsync` and `thenRunAsync` as you used to.

Comment: It can be implemented like that, but I think it would be a tidy and flexible implementation if the above is achieved. Is it a weird requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linear dependencies, you can just return a new `Runnable` that execute the tasks one by one. This way you have full control over the order of execution. A list of `Runnable` will not guarantee the order - you need the other class to respect the contract as well.

```
public Runnable getRunnable() {
    Runnable r1 = ...
    Runnable r2 = ...
    return ()->{
         r1.run();
         r2.run();
    };
}
```

I actually had an idea of supporting a Runnable Depenency Graph, not sure when that would be useful. I will try to code it after I got the time.

Comment: Thank you, it seems very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

One could argue a `Batch` class is supposed to supply a number of `Runnable` which have to be processed in order. So encapsulating a number of `Runnable` inside another `Runnable` might hide to much.

But I do understand your requirement to simplify the code down to `Runnable` A simple solution could be:

```
public class Batch implements Runnable{
    public List<Runnable> getRunnable() {
    Runnable r1 = // creating...
    Runnable r2 = // creating...
    // FIXME: demand that r2 run after r1 finishes
    return // List of r1, r2, ....
}

@Override
public void run(){
    for (Runnable r:getRunnable()){
        r.run();
    }
}
```

Of course this way your batch will be processed as one `Runnable` and not as a series of `Runnable`.

*Edit*

Once `Batch` implements `Runnable`, your class `Main` could look like this:

```
public class Main {
  private ExecutorService pool; // Initialized before executing main
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Batch> batches = // fetching...
    for(Batch batch : batches) {
      pool.submit(batch);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have an ExecuteService in another class `Main`, so `Batch` itself cannot be executed alone. But thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I don't see in what way it is relevant where the `ExecutorServices` resides. If `Batch` implements `Runnable`, it can be submitted to the executor.